# Troubleshooting the use of if/else inside a event function

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

I am having trouble using an if else to achieve a simple two-way celsius/fahrenheit conversion using basic HTML input fields and some background Javascript.

Basically, I want to be able to enter a value in C or F into one of the two inputs and then have the conversion appear in the other input. The Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion works OK, but nothing happens when entering numbers into the Fahrenheit input. My code is below

```js
var celsius = document.getElementById("Celsius");
    var fahrenheit = document.getElementById("Fahrenheit");

    celsius.addEventListener('input', conversion);
    fahrenheit.addEventListener('input', conversion);

    function conversion() {

    var celsiusvalue = document.getElementById("Celsius").value;
    var fahrenheitvalue = document.getElementById("Fahrenheit").value;
    const intcelsius = parseInt(celsiusvalue, 10);
    const intfahrenheit = parseInt(fahrenheitvalue, 10);

    if (this.id == "Celsius") {
    fahrenheit.value = ((intcelsius * 9)/5) + 32;
    }
    else {
    celsius.value == (((intfahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9);
    }
    }
```

```html
<section>

  <input id="Celsius" placeholder="Celsius"/><br/><br/>
  <input id="Fahrenheit" placeholder="Fahrenheit"/>

</section>
```

Can anyone help me out? Should I not be using if/else here and just use two different functions?

Comment: You have `celsius.value ==`, this should be a single `=` sign

Answer (score 1):

```
        celsius.value == (((intfahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9);
```

should be:

```
        celsius.value = (((intfahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9);
```

Comment: Omg I'm an idiot and shouldn't submit typo questions. Thank you so much for answering!

Comment: Haha, it happens to all of us.  If you aren't already using it, ESLint might help you catch a good amount of these bugs before you even run the code.  This rule in particular might have helped here, since === is a bit more explicit and noticeable than ==:

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq